# NodeJS script on Azure VM

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, azure, ssh

I've setup a Linux VM on Azure which has NodeJS and MongoDB installed.

Then I have a single node script that I need to be constantly running (it receives and sends Google push notifications generated from an Android app and saves to my MongoDB accordingly).

So far the only way I can get it to run is by connecting via ssh on my local machine, running the script with "node gcm.js", which works fine. But when I disconnect from the server the script stops running... So how do I run it without needing to connect with my local machine? A cron job that starts just one time? Or have I gone about this in completely the wrong way?

Comment: There are many ways to run script in background including but not limited to cron job, service and screen etc. but I'll suggest to post this question to appropriate forum such as http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks, think screen will let me do what I need. And point taken about using the correct forum.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there is a simple way for keeping the current process running as a background job.

Here is the steps below.

1. Connecting via ssh on local machine, then running the script `node gcm.js`.
2. Enter `Ctrl+Z` for stoping the current process, then you will see below, the `N` number of the `[N]+` below is the job id.

   ^Z 
   [N]+  Stopped                 node gcm.js
3. Enter `bg %N` to convert the `N` job from a stoped foregroud job into a background job.
4. Enter `disown -h %N` to remove the `N` job from the job list of the current shell, then the process will be running after closing the current ssh connection.

More details for these linux commands, I think you can easily get via search engine.

Hope it helps.